# Workbox - what to return when using setCatchHandler?

Tags: workbox

In the Workbox docs (v5), an example will send back the `Response.error()` object:

```
setCatchHandler(() => {
    return Response.error();
});
```

However, we need to support some mobile devices, which do not have the Response API - what should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `Response` is returned from the [handlerCallback](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing#%7EhandlerCallback) is then sent as-is to the main thread.

Answering with whatever response is handled as an error by your existing code should work.

Here is what `Response.error()` generates:

```
Response {
  body: null
  bodyUsed: false
  headers: Headers {}
  ok: false
  redirected: false
  status: 0
  statusText: ""
  type: "error"
  url: ""
}
```

And here is what `new Response(null, {status: 500})` generates:

```
Response {
  body: null
  bodyUsed: false
  headers: Headers {}
  ok: false
  redirected: false
  status: 500
  statusText: ""
  type: "default"
  url: ""
}
```

The only differences are `status` (`0 -> 500`) and `type` (`'error' -> 'default'`). The same minimal differences apply with `new Response(null, {status: 404})`. Also note that if you're using the Fetch API, a response with a error status does **not** resolve in a rejected promise, requiring an extra check on the `Response`'s `ok` property.

I've checked via [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=Response%20API) the availability of the different Response APIs for various platforms, but I've found they're not accurate. You can perform a live online test [here](https://snack.expo.io/9toHDy753) and [here](https://js.do/code/464270). `Response`'s `error()`, `ok` and `status` are available on all recent browsers for desktop and mobile.

Another option is to use a polyfill [like this](https://github.com/github/fetch) that overwrites the global `Response` object by one that contains a `error()` implementation, but I'm not feeling confident about this alternative.